# Internal server error on page with form Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

Hi I am getting this error message when I try to access my page after hosting it on a live web host. This error unfortunately does not appear on my testing servers. The hosting server has php version 7.1.19 and is running on apache.

```
    yii\base\ErrorException: An internal server error occurred. in /home/mywebhost/public_html/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php:317
    Stack trace:
    #0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleError(256, 'An internal ser...', '/home/mywebhost/...', 317, Array)
    #1 /home/mywebhost/public_html/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(317): trigger_error('An internal ser...', 256)
    #2 /home/mywebhost/public_html/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/widgets/ActiveField.php(178): yii\base\ErrorHandler::convertExceptionToError(Object(yii\base\InvalidConfigException))
    #3 /home/mywebhost/public_html/app/views/site/_clients.php(532): yii\widgets\ActiveField->__toString()
    #4 /home/mywebhost/public_html/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(336): require('/home/mywebhost/...')
    #5 /home/mywebhost/public_html/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(254): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('/home/mywebhost/...', Array)
    #6 /home/mywebhost/public_html/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(156): yii\base\View->renderFile('/home/mywebhost/...', Array, Object(app\controllers\SiteController))
    #7 /home/mywebhost/public_html/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(384): yii\base\View->render('_clients', Array, Object(app\controllers\SiteController))
    #8 /home/mywebhost/public_html/app/controllers/SiteController.php(72): yii\base\Controller->render('_clients', Array)
    #9 [internal function]: app\controllers\SiteController->actionClientDetails()
    #10 /home/mywebhost/public_html/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #11 /home/mywebhost/public_html/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
    #12 /home/mywebhost/public_html/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): yii\base\Controller->runAction('client-details', Array)
    #13 /home/mywebhost/public_html/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/client-details', Array)
    #14 /home/mywebhost/public_html/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
    #15 /home/mywebhost/public_html/index.php(7): yii\base\Application->run()
    #16 {main}
    2018-07-18 01:00:11 [196.103.192.115][-][mbgo1e37qtc3ilqdu6iivk2kv6][info][application] $_GET = [
        'r' => 'client-details'
    ]
```

My Active form is declared that I is said to be having a problem, and all other forms are also declared as such. All pages with a form are also returning the same error.

```
    <?php  
    use yii\widgets\ActiveForm; 
    ?>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['name'=>'clients','id'=>'client_details']]); ?>
    <div class="row pb40"> 
        <div class="clients-form  col-sm-12 col-md-12  col-lg-12 col-xs-12 pull-left">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10  col-lg-10 col-xs-10 pull-left">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6  col-lg-6 col-xs-6 pull-left">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'national_id')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6  col-lg-6 col-xs-6 pull-right">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'mobile_phone')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div> 
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6  col-lg-6 col-xs-6 pull-left">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6  col-lg-6 col-xs-6 pull-right">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'last_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>  
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6  col-lg-6 col-xs-6 pull-left">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6  col-lg-6 col-xs-6 pull-right">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'address')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div> 
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6  col-lg-6 col-xs-6 pull-left">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'country')->dropDownList(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\modules\config\models\Countries::find()->all(), 'name', 'name'));?>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6  col-lg-6 col-xs-6 pull-right">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'city')->dropDownList(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\modules\config\models\Cities::find()->all(), 'name', 'name'));?>  
                </div>   
            </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2  col-lg-2 col-xs-2 pull-right"> 
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6  col-lg-6 col-xs-6 pull-right"> 
                <?= $form->field($model, 'payment_channel')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->hiddenInput()->label('') ?>  
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div> 
    <div id="explantion"></div>  
        </div> 
        <a href="#payment" class="btn btn-dark-main btn-next-tabs pull-right">Next</a>
    <?php $form::end();?>
```

Below is also the model from which the form is created.

```
    <?php

    use Yii;

    class Clients extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

        public static function getDb() {
            return Yii::$app->get('connect1');
        }

        public function rules() {
            return [
                    [['first_name', 'last_name', 'mobile_phone', 'email', 'address', 'country', 'city', 'national_id'], 'required'],
                    [['display_record', 'payment_channel', 'company_id'], 'integer'],
                    [['total_amount'], 'number'],
                    [['created_on', 'updated_on'], 'safe'],
                    [['first_name', 'last_name', 'mobile_phone', 'email'], 'string', 'max' => 128],
                    [['address', 'country', 'city'], 'string', 'max' => 250],
                    [['national_id'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            ];
        }

        public function attributeLabels() {
            return [
                'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
                'first_name' => Yii::t('app', 'First Name'),
                'last_name' => Yii::t('app', 'Last Name'),
                'mobile_phone' => Yii::t('app', 'Mobile Phone'),
                'email' => Yii::t('app', 'Email'),
                'address' => Yii::t('app', 'Address'),
                'country' => Yii::t('app', 'Country'),
            ];
        }

        public static function find() {
            return new ClientsQuery(get_called_class());
        }

        public function getName() {
            return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
        }

    }
```

And below is the controller that I am working with

```
    <?php
    namespace app\controllers; 
    use yii\filters\AccessControl;
    use yii\web\Controller; 
    use yii\filters\VerbFilter;  

    class SiteController extends Controller {

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */ 
        public $layout = "//Public"; 

        public function behaviors() {
            return [
                'access' => [
                    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                    'only' => ['logout'],
                    'rules' => [
                        [
                            'actions' => ['logout'],
                            'allow' => true,
                            'roles' => ['*'],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'verbs' => [
                    'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                    'actions' => [
                        'logout' => ['post'],
                    ],
                ],
            ];
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function actions() {
            return [
                'error' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
                ],
                'captcha' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                    'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
                ],
            ];
        }


        /**
         * Displays homepage.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function actionIndex()
        { 
            return $this->render('_home_content');
        }

        public function actionClientsDetails()
        { 
            $model =  new \app\models\Clients(); 
            $model->payment_channel = 4; 
            return $this->render('_clients',['model'=> $model]);
        }

        public function actionOurGallery()
        {
            return $this->render('_gallery');
        } 
        /**
         * Displays about page.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function actionAbout() {
            return $this->render('about');
        }

    }
```

Comment: at a guess you've hardcoded the file path of your test server and the file path is different on your live server

Comment: The only thing that stand out is `InvalidConfigException` so you should double-check your configuration

Comment: @Joshua, I don't hard code paths, they are picked dynamically in Yii2

Comment: @PaulWakhungu Can you add your active form htmls in your question?

Comment: @ManikandanS I have added it in edit

Comment: @PaulWakhungu I guess the problem is here - app/views/site/_clients.php(532): yii\widgets\ActiveField->__toString(). In your template file _clients.php on line 532  you have some active form field which is having wrong configuration. Please check your self on that line or else post whole form, I will tell the which is causing the problem ;)

Comment: This is the line it is referring to `<?= $form->field($model, 'national_id')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>` .

Comment: @PaulWakhungu it seems correct. If your form is not big, add whole form in your question. it will be helpful to find out the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176219/discussion-between-manikandan-s-and-paul-wakhungu).

Comment: @PaulWakhungu your testing server php version and new hosting server php versions are same?

Comment: The testing server has php version 7.1.7,  the live one has 7.1.19, but the requirements.php says that should be okay.

Comment: Please go to the chat!

Comment: @PaulWakhungu show that line please: `/home/mywebhost/public_html/app/controllers/SiteController.php(72)`

Comment: It is the line that loads the form 'return $this->render('_clients',['model'=> $model]);'

Comment: What about this: app/views/site/_clients.php(532) ?

Comment: It is this line here
`<?= $form->field($model, 'national_id')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>`

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of discussions with @robsch in the chat, it was discovered that the problem was a missing directory `'assets'`. I created the folder `'assets'` and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this error when want to use captcha as a widget and the captcha action had an error.

```php
<?php 
echo $register_form->field($login_model, 'verifyCode')->widget(Captcha::className(), [
                'captchaAction' => '/core/frontend/default/captcha',
                'template' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6">{input}</div><div class="col-sm-6">{image} <a href="javascript:;" id="refresh-captcha"><span class="fa fa-refresh"></span></a></div></div>',
                'imageOptions' => [
                    'id' => 'my-captcha-image',
                    'style' => 'height: 35px',
                ],
            ]);
?>
```

my problem solved when I solved error on `captchaAction` route.